Types of car insurance rated per mileage
What are the types of car insurance policies out there that take into account mileage driven over the duration of the policy?
I know there are per-mile policies that use some kind of OBD2 GPS tracking device or some other kind of tracking device to carry out the billing. Other policies you submit estimated mileage and the premiums are adjusted accordingly upfront, while others are unlimited from what I understand.
I’m hoping to learn the formal names for each of three families of car insurance so I can communicate about them more fluently. What would the names or what is the industry terminology for the above types of policies?

I don't know if there are any special terms, most (all?) car insurers would want to know how much you drive. The risk is not linear per mile, and while there are some policies which give rebates based on your actual driving mileage compared to the estimate provided, they still require a reasonably accurate upfront estimate for pricing. The ones that don't would have a fixed component that's not dependent on mileage to cover for the risk gap.

Most policies I've seen have a single low - mileage - driver discount percentage, usually for cars that travel less than 3,000 miles per year.  Ask your insurance agent if you need something different.

Insurance norms and rules vary around the world. What country are you in?

I used to qualify for a low-mileage discount in southern California. I drove around 7-8k per year. The agent wanted to see the car every few years to verify the mileage. It was associated with Farmer's (Mid-century).

It looks like the terminology out in use is Per-Mile-Insurance vs Traditional Insurance, or pay-per-mile and traditional auto coverage
Pay Per Mile

This type of program has many names—usage-based, pay as you go, and pay per mile car insurance—but they are all based on the same basic idea. For the sake of this article we’ll refer to it just as pay per mile.[1]

Traditional Insurance

Drivers may be rewarded with low-mileage discounts on traditional policies if they are behind the wheel less than the average American, who typically drives around 14,263 miles annually (or about 1,200 miles per month). [1]


With traditional insurance, like the policies AAA offers, [you get] unlimited mileage. We don’t charge for mileage at all. You can drive as much as you want, and your insurance will be the same price. [2]

So bottom line the language pay-per-mile or traditional insurance with a low mileage discount applied. I think the second source about unlimited mileage may be inaccurate, maybe it should have stated you're free to purchase mileage  at any quantity and there'd be a corresponding commensurate premium for it.
[1] https://www.lemonade.com/car/explained/pay-per-mile-car-insurance/
[2] https://mwg.aaa.com/insurance/car/articles/agent-pay-per-mile-insurance

The second link demands your ZIP/Postal code and then redirects you to the general enquiries page for your code, so it doesn't tell you anything useful.

Most policies, including AAA, do genuinely allow unlimited miles - not "purchase mileage in any quantity". They are not "pay per mile".

I believe "pay per mile" is a lemonade product name. Unfortunately there's no way to check what exactly the conditions of the policy are through the link you provided, by my understanding is that they don't actually charge you as you drive but you either provide them an estimate, or provide them odometer readings after the fact, or both. I would be surprised if they don't have a fixed component as well.

it sounded like you get tracked live, and probably reconcile the accrued bill at some regular intervals: your mileage is usually determined using a simple mobile app or a plug-in telematics device in the car

@littleadv Nationwide also calls their product pay-per-mile. They track your miles via telematics daily, as there's a daily cap. There is indeed a fixed monthly portion, accounting for comprehensive.
